# Unable to install unoconv on Amazon Sagemaker

Tags: linux, package, fedora, libreoffice, unoconv

I need to convert some miscellaneous files (pptx, xlsx, dox) to PDFs, and I need to do it on Linux. I found that "good way" to do this is using the unoconv package.

The problem is that when I try to do `sudo yum install unoconv` it tells me that

```
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper, versionlock
No package unoconv available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I add the package to the available ones from command line?

the distro is:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Comment: I have no experience with Amazon Sagemaker and extremely little experience with AWS, but I still wonder; 1) why is Sagemaker using Amazon Linux AMI rather than Amazon Linux 2 (is there an upgrade?), 2) `unoconv` uses LibreOffice (is that available for AWS?), 3) could `unoconv` be part of Amazon's "extra packages"?  What happens if you try `sudo yum install --enablerepo=epel unoconv`?

Answer (score 0):

Unoconv is installed with pip:

```
python -m pip install unoconv
```

It's absolutely essential that you are running that command with the same Python executable as LibreOffice is using, or it won't work, as unoconv needs the LibreOffice libraries to run.